# Issues with using FLAASH on GeoEye data

Tags: remote-sensing, atmospheric-correction, geoeye, flaash

I am trying to carry out a FLAASH atmospheric correction on radiometricaly corrected GeoEye-1 spatial image (working within ENVI).
I am getting the wrong results from my FLAASH correction and believe that this is being caused by the Scale factor I have been using or the radiometrically corrected image being in the wrong units for the FLAASH correction to work.

I am using the Scale factor of 100 as the image is a 16 byte pixel value (also used 1 and 10 as recommend in ENVI help but had no luck).

As far as I can read the units in the GeoEye image are in `mW/(cm2-srt-nm-dn)` at the radometrically corrected level. However to carry out the FLAASH correction it should be in `µW/(cm2 * sr * µm)` and I do not know how to convert the one to the other.

Could you give me some advice about either of these options (converting the units or using a separate scale factor for each band)?